# How to cache Google App Engine queries - how to get query string/hash and affected tables?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I want to cache queries in memcache to speed up reading. For this I need some function creating some id for query.

```
class DeleteMe(db.Model)
    pass

query = DeleteMe.all()

# how to get query string/hash form query?
# how to get kind name from query?
```

I want do something like this (getQueryKey is function which always give same value for same query):

```
memcache.set(getQueryKey(query), list(query))
```

Please help me it can be db or ndb.

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar problem; here's my code:

```
    def keyFromQuery( query ):
            """
                    Derives a unique Key from a given query.
                    This Key is stable regardless in which order the filter have been applied
                    @param query: Query to derive key from
                    @type query: DB.Query
                    @returns: string
            """
            origFilter = [ (x, y) for x, y in query._get_query().items() ]
            for k, v in query._Query__orderings:
                    origFilter.append( ("__%s ="%k, v) )
            origFilter.append( ("____kind", query._model_class().kind() ) )
            origFilter.sort( key=lambda x: x[0] )
            filterKey = "".join( ["%s%s" % (x, y) for x, y in origFilter ] )
            return( sha256( filterKey ).hexdigest() )
```

Comment: Thanks for hint but this code is very danger for production. __x is mangled to not be accessed at all reason, _x is not public so better not use it - if it not stands other. Whatever this is what Google should implement!

Comment: Even though it's probably okay to use these methods, as there all single underscore (ie 'light' private).
If in doubt, you could even copy the appengine.ext.db module into your application to ensure it doesn't change
 (thought I'd recommend not doing this), as its only a wrapper around appengine.api.datastore, which itself only wraps appengine.datastore which finally quotes "is
designed to be the lowest-level API to be used by all Python datastore client libraries for executing queries. It provides a layer of protection so the actual RPC syntax can change without affecting client libraries."

Comment: You code is very good but Google not give permission to use __x and the mostly _x hint is very good I think nobody will give better! I've found quote in code but still think it is little risky since can loose backward compatibility but you do very good research.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really make sense. A query is not something that is worth caching: it's just a stateless object that is easily recreated in a line of code. Caching is for actual data, which is expensive to fetch from the datastore.

A better solution if you need to easily reference a series of queries might be to simply store them in a dictionary, either at module level or as a class attribute of the relevant model.

Comment: Read the question more carefully - he's asking for a way to get a suitable identifier for the results of a query by hashing/serialising the query itself, which isn't so unreasonable.

Comment: Read the question more carefully - it is related to cache query results not query.

Answer (score 1):

Use ndb and memcache the query results (keys_only).

```
def myquery_cached(flush_cache=False):
    key = 'My Query Key'    # make this unique to this query
    ctx = ndb.get_context()
    # if flush_cache is True, skip the cache and run the query
    myclass_keys = None if flush_cache else ctx.memcache_get(key).get_result()
    if not myclass_keys:
        myclass_keys = MyClass.query(...).fetch(keys_only=true)  # the actual query
        ctx.memcache_set(key, myclass_keys)    # store the keys
    return ndb.get_multi(myclass_keys)         # this uses ndb's caching
```

After this code is called once to fill the caches, each subsequent time it makes two memcache queries to retrieve all the results.

When you want to refresh the cache, call myquery_cached(True)